# Expand months between start date and end date in teradata

Tags: teradata

Need Query to expand the months between the start date and end date.
Below is one example of data.
Result is the output I would like to see.
Any help is much appreciated.

Example columns:

```
ID    start date, End date
300   08/20/2021  10/25/2021
```

Result:

ID, Dateexpand

300 08/2021

300 09/2021

300 10/2021

Comment: That's what Teradata's `EXPAND ON` [syntax](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Data-Manipulation-Language/July-2021/SELECT-Statements/EXPAND-ON-Clause) provides. You may also want to use the `PERIOD()` constructor along with functions such as `BEGIN()`, `END()`,`NEXT()`, `PRIOR()`.

Comment: Thanks Fred for your response. Can you please show the query I can use? I tried expand but somewhere it is failing. If you can send me the query that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Teradata's EXPAND on syntax ([documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/542VMPPqGwHBhF98pnTz9w)):

```
select
id,
start_date,
end_Date,
prd,
last(prd) as end_month,  --this will return the last date in the period
to_char(last(prd),'YYYYMM')
from
<your table>
expand on period (start_date,end_date) as prd BY ANCHOR PERIOD MONTH_BEGIN
```

I left all the columns in there so you can see what the PERIOD returns.

EDIT:
Period will not work if the ending date is not greater than the starting date.  If you have cases where this isn't true, you'll have to process those separately and union them together:

```
select
id,
to_char(last(prd),'YYYYMM')
from
<your table>
where end_date > start_date
expand on period (start_date,end_date) as prd BY ANCHOR PERIOD MONTH_BEGIN
union 
select
id,
to_char(start_date, 'YYYYMM')
from
<your table>
where end_date = start_date
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I really appreciate for your quick response. When executing this query but I am seeing an error as invalid period value constructor. The beginning bound must be less than the ending bound.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this query worked!!! ,
last(prd) as end_month this will give the end of the month. How do I get the start of the month in the same date format?

Comment: @Maddy - `begin(prd)` gives you the earliest date of the period.

Comment: Instead of UNION you can adjust the end date using`expand on period (start_date,case when end_date <= start_date then start_date +1)`